# Google Volley cause app to crash while running proguard

Tags: runtime-error, android-volley, android-proguard

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.bash.farah.SiginActivity$2.onResponse(Unknown Source) at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(Unknown
>   Source) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

---

Using 4.5.1 Gradle 
and com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0